# How do I optimize the below query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have two tables.

users:

```
id(primary key) parent_id   type     school_name
1                           school  my school
2                 1         school  my school
3                 1         school  my school
4                           abc
5                           xyz
```

subscription:

```
id(primary key) uid expiry         type      class
 1               1   somedate      valid      1
 1               1   somedate      invalid    2
 1               2   somedate      valid      1
 1               2   somedate      invalid    2 
 1               3   somedate      valid      1
 1               3   somedate      invalid    2
```

The first table has users. A parent user has a blank parent_id. The type for all parent and subchild users is the same school.

The second table contains the subscription. If a parent user has a subscription of class 1 and 2, then two rows will be there for this user and for each subuser of that parent. Class can be more, like 3 and 4. There is also a type of that class which can be valid, invalid, or blank.

Now I have an autocomplete box where a user types a school name and a list of all schools with that typed word are listed.

My user table has more than 15000 records, and my subscription table has more than 50000 thousand records. I know we can change the database structure and some other data inserting rules so that subscription can be identified only by parent_id. We have no need to insert a row for a subchild in subscription, but we cant change it now.

I am using the following query. I want to know what will happen if 5000 users use that autocomplete at the same time.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id,
                u.school_name
FROM users u,
     subscription s
WHERE u.school_name LIKE 'my%'
  AND u.type = 'school'
  AND u.parent_id = ''
  AND s.type != 'valid'
  AND u.id = s.uid
ORDER BY school_name
```

Comment: @AdrianBR both ids in table are primary key index.

Comment: if you cannot change anything in the database, the only thing you can try altering is order by left(school_name, 1000) to avoid having the query use the order by prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

give the school and ID, create a table with school name and ID. search for name from that table and use the ID to restrict the result set via an inner join with the rest of your data. You may also want to consider a composite index between u.id, u.school_name/school_id.

u.type should also be smallint not varchar. Map your text in a school_type_dimension table

if s.type is only valid/invalid, use bit or bool as 0/1, or enum if it has several options. This will speed up searches considerably.

try

```
alter table subscription add index `subscription_user ` (`uid`);
SELECT DISTINCT u.id,
                u.school_name
FROM users u 
inner join subscription s on s.uid=u.id

WHERE u.school_name LIKE 'my%'
  AND u.type = 'school'
  AND u.parent_id = ''
  AND s.type != 'valid'
ORDER BY school_name
```

Comment: i can not change the database structure now. I need to do all in what i have.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `users`
 ADD INDEX `comp_index` (type , parent_id , id ,school_name );

can you add indices? that would help. otherwise the query is optimised

Comment: i guess the problem is because of second table. as first table has 1 row to select but second row has to check in all 50000 records. I did the explain in sql and got 1 row in user and all rows of second table. i added index in type in second table but does not affect anything.

Comment: add index to uid in second table. run query above after

Comment: i have used indexing on both tables and now only 4 rows. i think it would work now. Wil it solve the problem?

Comment: should run considerably faster. Further improvements can be done by adding an index with length 1 to s.type, or changing s.type to enum(which would not change anything in db structure).

Comment: yes i have made index for s.type. it would run faster but would it affect when more than 5000 user use that query in one time?

Comment: I am pretty sure if 5000 do it at the same time, you will have a problem. Depends on many things (mysql version, server resources, server conf... ). You could be fine though, your data set is very small.

Comment: so would i need to improve the query now. as i dont think i can do other changes on that as now just 4 total rows in explain sql. with 50000 subscription data and 15000 user data. so now its server problem to serve the load.

Comment: rather than adding servers, I would normalize the database: user.Type can be smallint ID, s.type cal be bool, school name cna be an id from shcool table, etc. your query would then run SIGNIFICANTLY faster. 

short of that, yes, that query is pretty much optimal, so you'D have to upgrade the server or balance across servers if it gets too bad.

Comment: i think after adding indexes my query is optimized well. And i cannot change the database structure as it was build before.

Comment: Yep, query is as fast as it will get on this database structure.